# setOffscreenPageLimit(int) doesn't work on screen rotation

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm trying to save the data of forms contained in a `viewpager`.When I'm in `landscape` mode it works perfectly but when I rotate the screen all the data are gone and the fields are blank again.How to deal with that ?

The fragment in which I call the viewpager :

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main,
                container, false);
mViewPager = (ViewPager)rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter1(getChildFragmentManager());
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(6); 

        new setAdapterTask().execute();
        return rootView;
    }
private class setAdapterTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
          protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                       mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            }
    }
```

adpater :

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {


        switch (arg0) {
        case 0:
            Part1 p1= new Part1();
            p1.setRetainInstance(true);
            return p1;
        case 1:
            return new part2();
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is just to save data in `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)`and load them in `OnViewCreated`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried retaining the `Fragment`'s instance using `setRetainInstance(true)`?

Comment: you should set `setRetainInstance(true)` inside your `Fragment` declaration.

Comment: I tried as well I got the can't retain fragments that are nested in other fragments exception

Comment: why are you using AsyncTask? is your `Fragment` inside another `Fragment`? can you post more code?

Comment: in order to display a viewpager inside a fragment which is contained in a master/detail flow

Comment: `AsyncTask` is mainly used to perform background tasks on its `doInBackground()`. You are not using it. `onPostExecute()` runs on the UI `Thread`, so it is the same as if you call it directly from `onCreateView()`

Comment: but it's  not the reason for the exception right? or why it's blank when rotated?